# How can I generate a set of words that has dots in between?

Tags: excel

Example, for the word apple. I want the output to be

apple

a.pple

a.p.ple

and so on. I need to get all the possibilities. The only rule is it can't have two periods in a row and also no periods at the end or start.

How can I do this in excel? Even a simple .txt would be okay as well.

Comment: use replace funcation to replace "." with ""

Comment: This sounds more like a logic question than a programming one. Please first get your (iterative) algorithm written out and after that programming whouldnt be a big issue.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in Excel by using string formulas.  This is what my worksheet looks like:

[image: The word "apple" is in cell A1]

The formula in cell B2 is: =LEFT($A$1,A2)&"."&MID($A$1,A2+1,5)

Cell A1 has the string "apple", and cell A2 has the integer 0, B2 has the string ".apple" (which you don't want, so you can ignore this value).  I drag down the column of integers in column A from 0 to 5.

The "LEFT" formula takes the leftmost characters of a string, and then i insert the period between this and the following characters which are brought in using the MID formula.  Since the input for LEFT and MID is the integer value in column A, this will output in column B every such combination you are looking for. Note you MUST lock cell A1 in this formula, as the string will always be in cell A1.

Hope this helps!